# Store value in pointer var

Tags: c++

How to store int values in *pData  and display values from it?

```
  int id = 12;
  int age = 14;
  unsigned char* pData = new unsigned char[8];
  memcpy(pData,&id,4);/* using memcpy to copy */
  pData = pData + 4;
  memcpy(pData,&age,4);/* using memcpy to copy */
  // How to print value from buffer *pData
```

Comment: You are changing your allocated pointer location thereby losing your allocated position and you are assuming that sizeof(int) == 4, which is not really portable at all. You might as well have written `unsigned char *pData = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&id)` instead.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use a `char*`?

Comment: yeah.. @ CoffeeandCode

Comment: printf("%d",*pData); or std::cout << (int)*pData;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using `memcpy` to copy the bytes of an `int` into an unsigned char buffer, the only correct way to display the ints is to copy the bytes back into an int. For example:

```
int temp_int;
memcpy(&temp_int, pData, sizeof temp_int);
std::cout << temp_int << '\n';
memcpy(&temp_int, pData + sizeof temp_int, sizeof temp_int);
std::cout << temp_int << '\n';
```

Attempting to reinterpret the buffer as an `int` would cause undefined behaviour by violating the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: *"It may also violate alignment requirements"* - not so, given 5.3.4/11 "For arrays of char and unsigned
char, the difference between the result of the new-expression and the address returned by the allocation
function shall be an integral multiple of the strictest fundamental alignment requirement (3.11) of any object
type whose size is no greater than the size of the array being created.".  (There's a note further explaining the *"allocation overhead permits the common idiom of allocating character arrays into which objects of other types will later be placed."*). (I was suspicious too!).

Comment: @TonyD true, I originally answered as if it was a non-dynamic array

Answer (score 2):

you can change pData into int *, then you can print the int valve.

---

```
cout<<*((int *)pData);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
memcpy(pData,&id,4);
```

This line copies the four bytes data in id to pData as int but you declared it as char * .
if you declare it as int *pData = new int[2]; then you can ptint exact values.

```
 using namespace std;
 int id = 12;
 int age = 14;
 unsigned int* pData = new unsigned int[2];
 memcpy(pData,&id,4);
 pData = pData + 1;
 memcpy(pData,&age,4);
 pData = pData - 1;
 cout<<"ID:"<<pData[0]<<"\nAge:"<<pData[1]<<endl;
```

This will print the values.

Comment: second value 0 it is printing.

Comment: can you enter the output?

Comment: plus one for ur solution  yeah

Comment: use `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof *pData` instead of `4`

Comment: You're copying `int`s to an `unsigned int` array, so negative values will instead be displayed as large positive values... can use `int* pData = new int[2];` to fix.

Comment: although you may as well just write `pData[0] = id;` instead of `memcpy`

Answer (score 1):

You can print pData using reinterpret_cast operator :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(void)
{
    int id = 12;
    int age = 14;
    const size_t size = sizeof(int);
    unsigned char* pData = new unsigned char[2*size];
    memcpy(pData,&id,size);/* using memcpy to copy */
    pData = pData + size;
    memcpy(pData,&age,size);/* using memcpy to copy */
    std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<int*>(pData)<<std::endl;
    pData = pData - size;
    std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<int*>(pData)<<std::endl;
    delete []pData;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it will print last var value. How to print first var value.

Comment: @abhi312: undo your `pData = pData + 4;` first - i.e. `pData -= 4;`.  (You'll probably want the original pointer later to `delete[]` the memory.)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to allocate memory as `unsigned char*`, you can do it like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int id = 12;
    int age = 14;

    // const pointer to buffer which can contain 2 ints
    unsigned char* const pData = new unsigned char[2*sizeof(int)];

    // non-const pointer to operate on data
    unsigned char* pDataPtr = pData;

    memcpy(pDataPtr,&id,sizeof(int));
    pDataPtr += sizeof(int);
    memcpy(pDataPtr,&age,sizeof(int));

    std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<int*>(pData)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<int*>(pData + sizeof(int))<<std::endl;

    delete [] pData;

    return 0;
}
```