# Output difference on Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++

```
unsigned long id = 12;
unsigned long age = 14;
unsigned char* pData = new unsigned char[8];
memcpy(pData,&id,4);/* using memcpy to copy */
pData = pData + 4;
memcpy(pData,&age,4);/* using memcpy to copy */
std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(pData)<<std::endl;
pData = pData - 4;
std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(pData)<<std::endl;
```

**Output on linux**

> 14 60129542156

**on windows (vc++)**

> 14 12

Comment: Looks like a problem with the size of unsigned long in each platform, they might also be 64bit vs. 32bit. Try using sizeof(unsigned long) instead of the literal 4.

Comment: In the Visual Studio compiler `sizeof(long)` is 4 even on 64 bit systems. For GCC on 64 bit systems then `sizeof(long)` is 8.

Comment: you need to use sizeof(unsigned long)

Comment: check my answer below, do you really need memcpy() ? can't you just use `a[1] = b` or `a = &b`

Comment: @Nick i saw ur ans. but there u also used memcpy.

Comment: @abhi312: [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129580/store-value-in-pointer-var) got *lots* of answers and comments recommending use of `sizeof` - this one's a bit silly considering....

Comment: @JoachimPileborg gcc on Windows follows Windows model, so long is 32 bits even on gcc on 64-bit Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making the assumption that `sizeof(unsigned long)` is always 4.  This is not true.

Try this:

```
const size_t NBYTES = sizeof(unsigned long);
unsigned long id = 12;
unsigned long age = 14;
unsigned char* pData = new unsigned char[2 * NBYTES];
memcpy(pData,&id, NBYTES);/* using memcpy to copy */
pData = pData + NBYTES;
memcpy(pData,&age, NBYTES);/* using memcpy to copy */
std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(pData)<<std::endl;
pData = pData - NBYTES;
std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(pData)<<std::endl;
```

If you want to use explicit data sizes, then use the types defined in `<cstdint>`.  Documentation can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint).

Comment: Also, even if you use <cstdint>, still use sizeof().  It makes your code more maintainable if the type of something ever changes.

Answer (score 3):

```
memcpy(pData,&id,4);/* using memcpy to copy */
//               ^
```

You are assuming the `sizeof (unsigned long)` is `4` which may or may not be true on a system as it is implmentation dependent.

Use the following line for the consistent behaviour.

```
memcpy(pData,&id,sizeof id);/* using memcpy to copy */
```

Moreover the following line may cause problem if some day the size of your variables are more than 8. Change these also to `sizeof`

```
unsigned char* pData = new unsigned char[2 * sizeof (unsigned long)];
...
pData = pData + sizeof id;  // etc
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, mostly for backward compatibility reasons, `sizeof(long)` is 4 even on 64 bit. On linux `sizeof(long)` in x86-64 (the platform you're probably using) is instead 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

use sizeof() instead of 4 in your program.

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function, so calling it `sizeof()` is not correct. You can use it without parentheses

Comment: if sizeof is not a function then what do you say it is?

Comment: @MadhuKumar It's an operator.

Comment: [Why is sizeof considered as an operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1393582/995714). If it's a function, `sizeof somevariable` won't work and you must use `sizeof(somevariable)`

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned long` is different size if you are using different operating system.

On 32 bit machines, usually unsigned long is 32 bit (4 bytes).
On 64 bit, usually unsigned long is 64 bit (8 bytes).

On top of that, it depends what is the C/C++ compiler. E.g. What is true for some compiler, might be not true for another.

Last I do not see where you release the memory you allocated with `new`.

Here is your code using sizeof():

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

int main(){
    unsigned long id = 12;
    unsigned long age = 14;
    size_t size = sizeof(unsigned long);
    unsigned char* pData = new unsigned char[2*size];

    memcpy(pData, &id, size);/* using memcpy to copy */

    pData = pData + size;

    memcpy(pData, &age, size);/* using memcpy to copy */

    std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(pData)<<std::endl;

    pData = pData - size;

    std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(pData)<<std::endl;

    // do you need to release the dynamic memory?
    delete pData;

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps. Comment if I miss something.

**UPDATE:**

I seems to missread the code. I am updated the code.

I will give you updated version where pointer arithmetic is used:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

int main(){
    unsigned long id = 12;
    unsigned long age = 14;

    unsigned long* pData = new unsigned long[2];

    memcpy(pData, &id, sizeof(unsigned long));/* using memcpy to copy */

    pData++;

    memcpy(pData, &age, sizeof(unsigned long));/* using memcpy to copy */

    std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(pData)<<std::endl;

    pData--;

    std::cout<<*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(pData)<<std::endl;

    // do you need to release the dynamic memory?
    delete pData;

    return 0;
}
```

If I was you, I would do it like this - e.g. no sizeof, no & (address of).

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

int main(){
    unsigned long id = 12;
    unsigned long age = 14;

    unsigned long *pData = new unsigned long[2];

    pData[0] = id;
    pData[1] = age;

    std::cout << pData[1] << std::endl;

    std::cout << pData[0] << std::endl;

    delete pData;

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps. Comment if I miss something.

I saw the comment for Windows / Microsoft C++ and size of unsigned long. This might be true, but I still think sizeof() is the way to do it. With sizeof() code is more portable and might compile to different platform, even on platforms you have no knowledge about.

Comment: thanks for reply.
size_t size = sizeof(unsigned long);

unsigned char* pData = new unsigned char[2*size];
and second value is not coming proper.

Comment: wrong. `long` is always 32 bits on Windows, even 64-bit windows

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc you might be right, but I believe correct way is still with sizeof. Because under Linux or OSX or Digital Unix or HPUX situation might be different.